# Routing in MVC not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

I have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Property",
    "{language}/property/{propertyUrlId}",
    new { controller = "PropertyDetails", action = "Property" }
```

This is the Controller that should be called for that route:

```
public class PropertyDetailsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Property(string language, string propertyUrlId)
    {
```

etc.

And the following URL that should use that route:

```
http://domain.com/en-us/property/3
```

Instead, I get 404. Any ideas why?

---

Here are my routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Property",
        "property/{propertyUrlId}",
        //new { controller = "PropertyDetails", action = "Property" }, new { language = @"[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}" }
        new { controller = "PropertyDetails", action = "Property" }
    );
}
```

Didn't work with language, or with language/country, either.

Comment: The order of registering routing rules is important. Give us all routes that you are creating in order of registration.

Comment: Even after the suggested change, I'm still getting a 404. Anything else I can try?

Comment: @AndrewBarber your comment is incorrect. You WILL get a 404 if it matches another route, e.g. the mvc default route -> controller is not known -> 404

Comment: birdus: You *need* to post your entire set of route definitions, so we can see if another could be matching. I still think my deleted answer is what your problem is, but since you won't even try it...

Comment: @AndrewBarber mvc does not care about the name. It just follows the routing rule. Just imagine you have the default route. What happens if you visit /controllerDoesNotExist/actionDoesNotExist ? 404! Why? because the route IS a match.

Comment: By the way, this is an MVC app within a solution which is based on Sitecore, the CMS. My lead says Sitecore has some kind of bug which is causing this, but my impression was that this MVC page is functioning independently of the CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no reason to break {language} apart into two chunks in the route. As some of you stated, this is fine:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Property",
    "{language}/property/{propertyUrlId}",
    new { controller = "PropertyDetails", action = "Property" }
```

Second, I omitted some information which was crucial to the solving of this problem. It didn't occur to me to include this in my problem description, as I didn't know there was any relationship. The MVC project is in a solution which also contains a website (non-MVC) which is using the Sitecore CMS as its datastore. Sitecore was stripping out the language segment of the URL and storing it, itself. Once I learned that this was happening, I was able to deal with the problem.

I appreciate all the input, and I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Use "en-us" as a segment of the URL is completely fine. I guess you have registered other routes as well. Try to bring this route to the top of others and at least on top of the default route.

I have tested the scenario, it works just fine for me.

Comment: You mean I don't need to break apart en-us into two parameters? My problem seems to be somewhere else, then. This is the only route in my Global.asaxx currently.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have registered the default route before your Property route. Default route typically looks like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Just register your Property route BEFORE this default route and it will work.

**Why it fails?** (Assuming you are indeed registering default route first)

en-us -> is interpreted as controller

property -> is interpreted as action

Since you don't have a en-usController with a Property action -> 404

Comment: @AndrewBarber 100% sure. Just try it ;-)

Comment: I just did. I get a 404 when the intended route is not first, and a correctly-called controller action when it is first. +1

Comment: However, note that in a comment to superwalnut, birdus says that the route shown in the question is the *only* route... so the default route isn't even there (if birdus is correct)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I did see that comment but I believe this is the most likely explanation. I guess he means, 'It's the only route I've added'. Have run into cases before, where people think that the default route is never to be touched/removed.

Comment: I know; I wish he would post the routes he has. Although I guess if he's correct, he already has. heh

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want to have the structure of the url as:

```
http://domain.com/en-us/property/3
```

use this routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Property", // Route name
            "{language}/property/{propertyUrlId}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "PropertyDetails", action = "Property", propertyUrlId = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

if there is a default routing in your Global.asax file, like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Put the routint above this block of code.

And your Controller Action should look like this:

```
public ActionResult Property(int propertyUrlId)
{
 return View();
}
```